# Is it possible to setup Single sign-on for a Single Page Application that will initiate the SSO from an arbitrary (not pre-approved) domain?

Tags: security, single-sign-on, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal

Our scenario is the following:

- We have an SPA that we package and send to multiple customers.
- The customers **hosts the SPA on an arbitrary domain** like [www.unknown.com/spa/anything-goes](http://www.unknown.com/spa/anything-goes), or [www.also-unknown.com/spa/really-anything-goes](http://www.also-unknown.com/spa/really-anything-goes), etc.
- The customer also **opens the SPA in a popup window and injects a service to communicate back and fourth from the popup (the SPA) and the main window**.
- The SPA uses our own API service, lets call it [www.backend.com](http://www.backend.com), as a backend.
- The SPA also uses the service that is injected into the popup window by the opener (the customer website), meaning the main popup (where the SPA is loaded) **window can't directly redirect to a common login page,** because that will interrupt the connection to the injected service, and we can't modify the customer code to make it more robust).
- We want to let the user of the SPA authenticate against our backend ([www.backend.com](http://www.backend.com)) using SSO (their Microsoft credentials)

For any given (fixed) domain, we can make this work by approving the exact domain as an allowed `Redirect URI` in AzureAd, and just using the `MSAL` in the SPA.

But how would you go about using SSO when you don't know ahead of time which `Redirect URIs` to add in AzureAd?

We can't re-direct the SPA to a common login page (cleared in AzureAd), because that would break the connection to the injected service.

The [msal-browser](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) library has an option to use a popup window instead of a redirect directly in the SPA window, but this option also needs a pre-approved `Redirect URI`.

I'm thinking we may need to implement custom logic to let our SPA open a popup window that navigates to a page we can pre-approve as a `Redirect URI`, that itself has the MSAL library and does the SSO login and communicates the result back to our SPA. But before I attempt a custom solution like that, I wonder if maybe I'm missing something.

Is there a more standard, less "hacky", solution that I have missed?

We would appreciate any input, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually went with the solution I hinted at in the question:

1. Publish a simple page including the `MSAL` library on a "central" location that we can pre-approve in AzureAD. Let's call that the **C**entral **SSO**-page (CSSO).
2. Let each SPA, running on what ever domain they want, open a popup with the CSSO. This runs the MSAL and completes the login.
3. CSSO has logic that, on login-completion, communicates back to the SPA, using `window.postMessage("Some message", "https://somerandomdomain.com")`
4. The SPA sets up a listener `window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage(){..logic here})`.

The drawbacks are, as far as I can tell, mostly that you need to make sure you are posting the message so that only the correct window can receive it.

Another drawback is that popups are often blocked, but in our case that is unlikely since our SPAs are running from domains where the main way of loading our SPAs is through a popup, so for the user to even see our SPA, popups must already be allowed. Still, some fallback logic is needed to open the popup manually with a click (which seems to circumvent the default block of popups).